# Can I comment preprocessor macros in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macros, comments, preprocessor

I have a lots of preprocessor macros in my projects. Recently, I don't understand how they work, and got tired open the define file too much. Can I comment on those preprocessors so I don't have to open the define files? If yes, then how?

For example:

```
#define X @"NO"
```

I've tried.

```
/** string "NO" */
#define X @"NO"
```

but no hope.